# Find value of n in C(n,r), given r (combinations)

Tags: combinatorics

Hi
Working with combinatorial notation nCr = (n!)/(n!(n-r)!)
Note nCr is written as C(n,r) and C(n,r) = C(n,n-r)

The question is:

> Find the value(s) of *n* if: C(n,3) = C(n,45)

Plugging that into combinatorial notation I get $\frac{n!}{3!(n-3)!} = \frac{n!}{45!(n-45)!}$
Cross multiplying and then dividing both sides by n! I'm left with $(45!)(n-45)! = (3!)(n-3)!$
This is where I'm stuck.

Anyone can show a way to proceed? Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We know by identity that

$$\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n}{n-k} $$

So we can see that to find values of $n$ such that

$$ \binom{n}{3} = \binom{n}{45} $$

We could say that $k = 3$ and $n-k = 45$ which gives us $n=48$.

Answer (score 2):

$45*44*...*4=(n-3)*(n-4)*...*(n-46)$

$$n-3=45\\
n-4=44\\
...\\
n-46=4$$

n=48 is certainly one possibility.
Now assume that you switch one of the equations such as the first two
$$n-3=44\\
n-4=45\\
...\\
n-46=4$$

You will always find there is no solution. So 48 is the only answer.

$$\frac{48!}{3!45!}=\frac{48!}{45!3!}$$

Answer (score 0):

C(n,3)=C(n,n-3)=C(n,45)
From above n-3=45, n=48 is an obvious solution.
Now let 48+k, k>0 be a solution too. Then you get:
45!(3+k)!=3!(45+k)!
1=[46/4]*[47/5]...*[(45+k)/(3+k)]
But it is obvious RHS>LHS. So k>0 cant be true. Now assume solution is of form 48-k,k>0. Then:
45!(3-k)!=3!(45-k)!
1=[(3-k+1)/(45-k+1)]*[(3-k+2)/(45-k+2)]...
Now RHS<LHS. So this is not possible either. Therefore 48 is the only solution.

Comment: Maybe,  could you use **MathJax** to write your answer?